# Certmgr - Self-signed certificate without private key is not updated

Tags: c++, windows, certificate, private-key, cryptoapi

I am working with self-signed certificates and certificate manager of Windows OS.

First of all, I have created a self-signed certificate "RootCA" which has a private/public key pair assigned, nevertheless I have destroyed private key of this certificate with the next certutil.exe command succesfully:

```
certutil -user -delkey "RootCA"
```

Also, I have check refreshing and exporting private key and it is not possible, because it has been destroyed.

The problem is when I visualize "RootCA" in Certificate Manager after destroying private key, "General" tab indicates that "**You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.**":

[image]

My question is:

Are there any way to update/remove previous certificate information? And if yes, is it possible to do it programmatically?

Comment: call `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` with `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID`. and *possible to do it programmatically?* - senseless question, because all in the end done programmatically

Comment: @RbMm That's it! setting ´pvData´ parameter of ´CertSetCertificateContextProperty´ function to ´NULL´, solves the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Microsoft CryptoAPI setting `pvData` parameter of `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` function to `NULL` solves the problem.